# facebook style menu implementation

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, menu, responsive-design

I am trying to put together a responsive site that works on a desktop/ipad/iphone/android tablet etc.

I am trying to add in the facebook style left hand menu - the one that has the three lines that when you click the menu slides in and then the and the content is moved over

the problem i am having is that i have set the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

so when i slide in content it extends the viewport even if i set the container to have a overflow hidden. Now i know i could just slide the menu in over the content but this is not what the client wants

I am doing the slide in of the menu using css transitions and this seems to be smooth rather than jQuery.

has anyone had a similar problem / can suggest a way round doing this?

cheers

dan

Answer (score 0):

so far have found this

http://tech.xtremelabs.com/html5-facebook-style-sliding-menu-using-twitter-bootstrap-collapse/

this also has a working jsfiddle example